# Efficiently insert data in to database in java

Tags: java, database, multithreading

I'm building an application that has a database that solely will be used for logging purpose. We log the incoming transaction id and its start and end time. There is no use for the application itself from this database. Hence I want to execute this insert query as efficient as possible without affecting the application itself. My idea is to execute the whole database insert code in a separate thread. So in this way, the database insert will run without interfering the actual work. I would like to know whether there is any design patter related to this kind of scenario. Or else whether my thinking pattern is correct for this.

Comment: What you want is either a queue such as rabbitmq or an [executor service](https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial). Search a bit for "java queue" or "java executor", you'll find something you like.

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking pattern is right.  Post your generated data from your main thread(s) into a safe-for-multi-threading blocking queue, and have the logging thread loop block waiting for a message to appear in the queue, then sending that message to the database and repeating.

If there is a chance, however small, that your application may be generating messages faster than your logging thread can process them, then consider giving the queue a maximum capacity, so that the application gets blocked when trying to enqueue a message in the event that the maximum capacity is reached. This will incur a performance penalty, but at least it will be controlled, whereas allowing the queue to grow without a limit may lead to degraded performance in all sorts of other unexpected and nasty ways, and even to out-of-memory errors.

Be advised, however, that plain insert operations (with no cursors and no returned fields) are quite fast as they are, so the gains from using a separate thread might be negligible.

Try running a benchmark while doing your logging a) from a separate logging thread as per your plan, and b) from within your main thread, and see whether it makes any difference.  (And post your results here if you can, they would be interesting for others to see.)

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, the best idea is to make an Java + RabbitMq broker + Background process architecture.

For example:

1. Java process enqueued a JSON message in RabbitMq queue. This step can be done asynchronously through ExecutorService class if you want a thread pool. Anyway, this task can be done synchrounously due to high enqueue speed of RabbitMq.
2. Background process connects to queue that contains messages and start to consuming them. This process task is to read and intrepret message by message and make the insert in database with its content information.

This way, you will have two separate processes and database operations won't affect main process.